# How to avoid navigating to next until Task is complete?

Tags: android, kotlin, task

I have following `clickListener` on one of fragments

```
 binding.btnCamera.setOnClickListener {
        val photo = takePhoto()
        
        val prediction = MachineLearning().predict(photo)
       
        val action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstToSecond(prediction)

        findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

**MachinLearing.kt** `predict()` function looks like below which contain a task which is executed asynchronously.

```
fun predict(photo: Bitmap): Boolean {

    val conditions = CustomModelDownloadConditions.Builder()
        .requireWifi()
        .build()

    FirebaseModelDownloader.getInstance()
        .getModel(modelName, DownloadType.LOCAL_MODEL_UPDATE_IN_BACKGROUND, conditions)
        .addOnSuccessListener { customModel ->
           ...
        }
        .addOnFailureListener{
           ...
        }
    ...
}
```

I want to halt the navigation to the next fragment until the `Task` inside the `predict()` is complete.

Due to asynchronous nature of `Task`. `Task` completion less likely to happen before fragment navigation. If fragment navigation happened then the `onDestroy()` will be called in current fragment causing `MachineLearning` object to garbage collected, so `Task` completion will not happen at all.

So how could I wait for Task completion to happen before the fragment navigation?

Comment: Primitively, you should pass a callback into `predict` which triggers when the work is complete. But as you're using Kotlin I would recommend looking into suspend functions instead.

Comment: @user158 my best guess is because people see hundreds of asynchronous questions that aren't a problem but a lack of understanding of how asynchronous programming works. Check my answer, it might help you.

Comment: @user158 why mixing subjects would be a valid excuse?

Comment: @user158 you don't know subject A yet you mention subject B, mentioning subject B doesn't compensate not knowing A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods `addOnCompleteListener` and `addOnFailureListener` are callbacks. That means is asynchronous, so whatever the method `predict` is returning, it can happen before or after those methods are triggered. There are 2 options: add another callback or transform it into suspend.

Callback:

```
fun predict(photo: Bitmap, predictionDelegate: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    //...
    addOnCompleteListener { model ->
        //do your thing and then call the callback
        predictionDelegate.invoke(yourCalculatedBoolean)
    }
    .addOnFailureListener...//do the same

}
```

And then for calling it:

```
MachineLearning().predict(photo) { prediction ->
    val action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstToSecond(prediction)

    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

The other alternative is to make it suspend:

```
suspend fun predict(): Boolean() {
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<Boolean()
    //your thing
    enter code here
    .addOnSuccessListener { model ->
        //do your thing and then update the defferred
        deferred.complete(yourCalculatedBoolean)
    }
    .addOnFailureListener...//do the same

    return deferred.await()
}
```

And then for calling it

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val prediction = MachineLearning().predict(photo)
       
    val action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstToSecond(prediction)

    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

I'm assuming you are in a `Fragment` or in an `Activity` due to the binding, so you should have `lifecycleScope`.

Comment: @user158 take a look again